Approximate a reaction-diffusion system by a "diffussion-then-reaction" system
Consider a 1D reaction-diffusion system with a scalar diffusion rate and a logistic reaction function:
$$\frac{du}{dt} = D \nabla^2 u + \rho u(1-u).$$
Suppose the spatial domain is $\mathcal{X}=[0,10]$.
The initial condition $u_0$ is $\phi(x)$, e.g. a short and narrow peak on the interval $\mathcal{X}$. Then, I did two simulations:
Simulation 1: Regular Simulation
Settings: $D=0.7$, $\rho=0.6$, time domain $\mathcal{T}_1=[0,20]$.
The following figure visualizes the PDE solution.

Simulation 2: Diffusion-Then-Reaction
Settings:

Diffusion-only simulation $D=0.7$, $\rho=0$, time domain $\mathcal{T}_1=[0,20]$
Continuing with the ending state of the previous diffusion-only simulation, do the reaction-only simulation with $D=0$, $\rho=0.6$ on $\mathcal{T}_2=[20,40]$

The following plot shows the 2nd stage of this simulation:

Comparison and Question
You can see that the two results are kind of similar. The question is, whether we can tell something theoretically about approximating the regular reaction-diffusion system by a diffusion-then-reaction one.
The question is raised from a PDE parameter estimation task based on the surrogate method, and is somehow related to the identifiability of $D$ and $\rho$.

I suspect that they only look similar because the diffusion term dominates the nonlinearity in the regime of the initial condition and the chosen parameter values. If you waited longer before switching to the reaction system then the resulting growth bump would be almost uniform in space. This could yield the wrong steady-state if $\rho$ is large enough that a non-uniform mode becomes unstable. As for identifiability, I don't see any reason they aren't mutually identifiable. The system can be nondimensionalized via $\tau = Dt$ to obtain
$$
u_\tau = \Delta u + \kappa u(1-u),
$$
where $\kappa = \frac{\rho}{D}$, so the only qualitatively relevant physical quantity is the relative timescale of the reaction and diffusion terms. This means that two systems can exhibit the same qualitative behaviors if they share the same $\kappa$, but if one knows the absolute timescale from, e.g., snapshots $u(t_1)$, $u(t_2)$, $\dots$ so that the absolute timescales can be determined then they should be identifiable. That being said, I suspect that they may be very difficult to identify in certain regimes where one terms dominates, for example.
